# Странная утечка памяти

Tags: c++, com, direct2d

Я знаю место где она может быть, но что бы я не пробовал применить туда, утечка не пропадает.

Происходит в методе `resize()` где производится перерасчет `rect` для отрисовки текста, при всем при этом я уже было подумал сделать отдельный класс для управления указателями, т.к. ни один из указателей из библиотеки `std` не помог.

Вот сам кусок кода в котором по моему мнению происходит утечка:

```
void graphics::resize()
{
    IDWriteTextLayout* layout;
    GetClientRect(window_handle_, &window_rect_);
    InvalidateRect(window_handle_, &window_rect_, false);

    HRESULT result = dwrite_factory_->CreateTextLayout(copy_of_str_.c_str(),
        copy_of_str_.length(),
        dw_text_format_,
        window_rect_.right - window_rect_.left,
        window_rect_.bottom - window_rect_.top, reinterpret_cast<IDWriteTextLayout**>(&layout));

    check_hr(result);

    result = hwnd_render_target_->Resize(D2D1::SizeU(window_rect_.right - window_rect_.left,
                                                     window_rect_.bottom - window_rect_.top));

    DWRITE_TEXT_METRICS met;
    layout->GetMetrics(&met);
    metrycs_ = met;
    if (FAILED(result))
    {
        _com_error err = result;
        MessageBoxW(window_handle_, err.ErrorMessage(), L"Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        return;
    }

    std::wstringstream string_stream;
    string_stream << L"Client size — Width: " << window_rect_.right - window_rect_.left << ", Height: " << window_rect_.
        bottom - window_rect_.top;
    copy_of_str_ = string_stream.str();

    render();

    layout->Release();
}
```

Так же ниже приведу полный код класса.

```
#pragma once
#include <d2d1.h>
#include <dwrite.h>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include "button_base.h"

class graphics
{
public:
    struct dpi_data { float x; float y; };
private:
    gui::button_base* button_;
    ID2D1Factory* factory_;
    ID2D1HwndRenderTarget* hwnd_render_target_;
    ID2D1RenderTarget* render_target_;
    IDWriteTextLayout* dwrite_text_layout_;
    IDWriteTextFormat* dw_text_format_;
    IDWriteFactory* dwrite_factory_;
    ID2D1SolidColorBrush* black_brush_;
    HWND window_handle_;
    RECT window_rect_;
    dpi_data current_dpi_data_;
    std::map<std::wstring, IDWriteTextFormat*> fonts_;
    static bool check_hr(HRESULT hr);
    DWRITE_TEXT_METRICS metrycs_;

    std::wstring copy_of_str_;
public:
    graphics();
    ~graphics();
    bool init(HWND hwnd);
    void begin_draw() const;
    void end_draw() const;
    void render();

    IDWriteTextFormat* get_text_format(std::wstring font_name);
    void draw_text(std::wstring font_name, std::wstring text, int x, int y) const;
    void resize();

    dpi_data get_dpi_data();
};
```

```
#include "graphics.h"
#include <comdef.h>
#include <locale>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
#include <memory>

bool graphics::check_hr(HRESULT hr)
{
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        _com_error err = hr;
        MessageBoxW(nullptr, err.ErrorMessage(), L"Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

graphics::graphics() : button_(nullptr), factory_(nullptr), hwnd_render_target_(nullptr), render_target_(nullptr),
                       dwrite_text_layout_(nullptr), dw_text_format_(nullptr),
                       dwrite_factory_(nullptr),
                       black_brush_(nullptr), window_handle_(nullptr)
{
    window_rect_ = {0,0,0,0};
}

graphics::~graphics()
{
    if (black_brush_)
    {
        black_brush_->Release();
        black_brush_ = nullptr;
    }

    if (factory_)
    {
        factory_->Release();
        factory_ = nullptr;
    }

    if (hwnd_render_target_)
    {
        hwnd_render_target_->Release();
        hwnd_render_target_ = nullptr;
    }

    if (!fonts_.empty())
    {
        for (auto font : fonts_)
        {
            font.second->Release();
        }

        fonts_.clear();
    }

    if (dwrite_text_layout_)
    {
        dwrite_text_layout_->Release();
        dwrite_text_layout_ = nullptr;
    }

    if (dwrite_factory_)
    {
        dwrite_factory_->Release();
        dwrite_factory_ = nullptr;
    }
}

bool graphics::init(const HWND hwnd)
{
    window_handle_ = hwnd;

    HRESULT result = D2D1CreateFactory(D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED, &factory_);
    if (!check_hr(result))
    {
        return false;
    }

    RECT rect;
    GetClientRect(window_handle_, &rect);
    result = factory_->CreateHwndRenderTarget(D2D1::RenderTargetProperties(),
                                              D2D1::HwndRenderTargetProperties(
                                                  window_handle_,
                                                  D2D1::SizeU(rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top)),
                                              &hwnd_render_target_);

    if (!check_hr(result))
    {
        return false;
    }

    result = DWriteCreateFactory(DWRITE_FACTORY_TYPE_SHARED, __uuidof(dwrite_factory_),
                                 reinterpret_cast<IUnknown **>(&dwrite_factory_));

    if (!check_hr(result))
    {
        return false;
    }


    result = dwrite_factory_->CreateTextFormat(L"Ubuntu", nullptr, DWRITE_FONT_WEIGHT_NORMAL, DWRITE_FONT_STYLE_NORMAL,
                                               DWRITE_FONT_STRETCH_NORMAL, 14, L"", &dw_text_format_);

    if (!check_hr(result))
    {
        return false;
    }


    result = dw_text_format_->SetParagraphAlignment(DWRITE_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT_NEAR);
    if (!check_hr(result))
    {
        return false;
    }
    result = dw_text_format_->SetParagraphAlignment(DWRITE_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT_NEAR);
    if (!check_hr(result))
    {
        return false;
    }

    result = hwnd_render_target_->CreateSolidColorBrush(D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF::Gray), &black_brush_);
    if (!check_hr(result))
    {
        return false;
    }

    GetClientRect(window_handle_, &window_rect_);

    get_dpi_data();

    button_ = new gui::button_base(&hwnd_render_target_, &dwrite_factory_, L"Button Text", &dw_text_format_);
    button_->init(10, 10, 0, 0, {5,5,5,5});

    std::wstringstream string_stream;
    string_stream << L"Client size — Width: " << window_rect_.right - window_rect_.left << ", Height: " << window_rect_.
        bottom - window_rect_.top;
    copy_of_str_ = string_stream.str();

    resize();

    return true;
}

void graphics::begin_draw() const
{
    hwnd_render_target_->BeginDraw();
}

void graphics::end_draw() const
{
    hwnd_render_target_->EndDraw();
}

void graphics::render()
{
    begin_draw();

    hwnd_render_target_->Clear(D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF::WhiteSmoke));

    draw_text(L"ubuntu", copy_of_str_, (window_rect_.right - window_rect_.top) - metrycs_.width - 10, 10);

    draw_text(L"ubuntu", L"Text Clipped to left bottom. Test Unicode: 特にあなたのために。", 10,
              window_rect_.bottom - window_rect_.top - 25);

    button_->draw();

    end_draw();
}

IDWriteTextFormat* graphics::get_text_format(const std::wstring font_name)
{
    const std::map<std::wstring, IDWriteTextFormat*>::iterator it = std::find_if(
        fonts_.begin(), fonts_.end(), [&](const std::pair<const std::wstring, IDWriteTextFormat*>& p)
        {
            return p.first == font_name && p.second != nullptr;
        });
    if (it != fonts_.end())
    {
        return (*it).second;
    }

    return nullptr;
}

void graphics::draw_text(const std::wstring font_name, std::wstring text, const int x, const int y) const
{
    hwnd_render_target_->DrawTextW(text.c_str(), text.length(), dw_text_format_,
                                   D2D1::RectF(float(x), float(y), window_rect_.right, window_rect_.bottom), black_brush_,
                                   D2D1_DRAW_TEXT_OPTIONS_CLIP);
}

void graphics::resize()
{
    IDWriteTextLayout* layout;
    GetClientRect(window_handle_, &window_rect_);
    InvalidateRect(window_handle_, &window_rect_, false);

    HRESULT result = dwrite_factory_->CreateTextLayout(copy_of_str_.c_str(),
        copy_of_str_.length(),
        dw_text_format_,
        window_rect_.right - window_rect_.left,
        window_rect_.bottom - window_rect_.top, reinterpret_cast<IDWriteTextLayout**>(&layout));

    check_hr(result);

    result = hwnd_render_target_->Resize(D2D1::SizeU(window_rect_.right - window_rect_.left,
                                                     window_rect_.bottom - window_rect_.top));

    DWRITE_TEXT_METRICS met;
    layout->GetMetrics(&met);
    metrycs_ = met;
    if (FAILED(result))
    {
        _com_error err = result;
        MessageBoxW(window_handle_, err.ErrorMessage(), L"Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        return;
    }

    std::wstringstream string_stream;
    string_stream << L"Client size — Width: " << window_rect_.right - window_rect_.left << ", Height: " << window_rect_.
        bottom - window_rect_.top;
    copy_of_str_ = string_stream.str();

    render();

    layout->Release();
}

graphics::dpi_data graphics::get_dpi_data()
{
    dpi_data tmpp;
    memset(&tmpp, 0, sizeof(dpi_data));
    factory_->GetDesktopDpi(&tmpp.x, &tmpp.y);
    current_dpi_data_ = tmpp;
    return current_dpi_data_;
}
```

Comment: Странно, что вы вызываете `layout->GetMetrics(&met);`, не проверяя предварительно `result`.

Comment: @VladD, result проверяется `check_hr(result);`

Comment: Нет, эта функция ничего не делает, кроме MessageBox'а. Загляните в неё. Вы ж игнорируете её возвращаемое значение.

Comment: хм, точно, но все равно установив освобождение при проверке, ничего толком не изменилось, память не сильно, но очень медленно продолжает расти.

Comment: Для начала стоит начать использовать умные указатели и перенести содержимое метода `Init` в конструктор.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, вот, например, возможность для утечки.

Вы создаёте `layout` через `CreateTextLayout`, затем переписываете `result` возвращаемым значением `hwnd_render_target_->Resize`. Если это возвращаемое значение не пройдёт проверку `if (FAILED(result))`, вы выходите из функции, не освободив `layout`.

Comment: Это может быть и не единственной проблемой. Например, вы в деструкторе не освобождаете `button_` и может быть что-то ещё.